# CodeIgniter show template on all controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 controllers, members and pages. The pages controller manages the page redirecting.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home') {
        if (!file_exists("application/views/pages/" . $page . ".php"))
            show_404();

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

}

class Members extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function login() {
        //login stuff here
        $this->load->view("pages/login");
    }

}
```

Those are my routes:

```
$route['members/(:any)'] = 'members/$1';
$route['members'] = 'members';

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

While trying to enter any page, for example, let it be the default page`home`. I can see the header and footer.
But if I'll try going to `members/login` I'll get only the content of the login view, but not the header and footer.

I can understand the problem clearly, but I need a solution. I'm new to the MVC model.

What solution can you offer me?

Comment: You have a typo in your contrustor. It says "consturct" instead of "construct"

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistent layout on all your pages, then you should follow these steps,

Open the application/core folder in your project and create MY_Controller.php file and write this code in it

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

 public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
 }

 public function loadPage($contentView = false, $data = array()){
      if(!$contentView) $contentView = 'home';
      $this->load->view('header', $data);
      $this->load->view($contentView, $data);
      $this->load->view('footer', $data);
 }

}
```

now modify your controllers

```
class Pages extends MY_Controller {

public function view($page = 'home') {

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $this->loadPage($page, $data);
}

}
```

Comment: But they are different controllers. I want the users to see the header and footer on each page.